# How to pass multiple API calls?

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a simple validation API call like this:

```
client = Client(
    token='{{YOUR_TOKEN_HERE}}',
    key='{{YOUR_KEY}}',
    environment='prod'
)

lookup_api = client.validations

result = lookup_api.list(number="{{NUMBER}}")

if result['status'] == 200:
    print(result['data'])
else:
    print("An error occurred." + str(result['status']))
    print(result['data'])
```

**I want to pass multiple different tokens and multiple numbers, how should I do it?**

I tried one token with multiple numbers and it worked, but I have been stuck on passing multiple tokens to multiple numbers for hours.

Here was my attempt:

```
tokens = ['112233','223344']
key='10000-000'
environment='prod'

clients = [Client(tokens=token, key=key, environment=environment) for token in tokens]

lookup_api = [list(clients=x).validations for x in clients]

results = [lookup_api.list(number=x) for x in numbers]

for result in results:

if result['status'] == 200:
print(result['data'])
else:
print("An error occurred." + str(result['status']))
print(result['data'])
```

Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(clients=x)` isn't proper syntax.

If you want to call the list function of `client.validations` like you had before you'd want this

```
results = [c.validations.list(number=n) for n in numbers for c in clients]
```

Otherwise, use a regular loop

```
for c in clients:
   for n in numbers:
       result = c.validations.list(number=n)
       status = result['status']
       data = result['data']
       if status != 200:
           print("An error occurred. " + str(status))
       print(data)
```